# Install Apache with a mvc application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, apache, webserver

Is it possible to add an Apache web server to an MVC project so that at the end you get an installation that installs the web server and moves the web page to the right folder?
Or exactly the other way around, is there an Apache installation that you give your website to so it goes straight to the right folder?
Does something like this exist in an easy way? Or maybe not with Apache but with a other application?

Answer (score 1):

if I understand your question you want to automate the installation of "PHP/Apache" websites using "ASP.net MVC app"

I've done this before, I used [Plesk CLI](https://docs.plesk.com/en-US/onyx/cli-win/getting-started-with-commandline-utilities.44076/) to create user accounts, databases, copy files ... etc.
You may want to use [Cpanel UAPI](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/DD/Guide+to+UAPI) for doing this tasks on remote Linux server.

Comment: yeah thats what I want. I forgott to say that I am using Windows. I just want to get an easy to install Website with little to no configuration from the user.

Comment: yes I did it on windows too, but you need Plesk installed on you Windows server to simplify this task, otherwise you need to do your own hardwork calling scripts for creating and configuring domains, sites, databases ... and even managing server resource limitation and subscription plans.